# count from multiple tables in MySQL/oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, hibernate

there are 4 tables:A,B,C,D 
there is an id:4(input) 
the query should print the number of times the id is present in the tables

EX:

```
in table A id:4 occurs 5 times
in table B id:4 occurs 7 times
in table C id:4 occurs 3 times
in table D id:4 occurs 1 times
```

output:

```
Table name       No of occurence

A                   5
B                   7
C                   3
D                   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like that:

```
select 'A', count(*) from a where id = 4
union all
select 'B', count(*) from b where id = 4
union all
select 'C', count(*) from c where id = 4
union all
select 'D', count(*) from d where id = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the `union all`

```
select 'A' as Name, count(*) as occurence from tablea where id = ?
union all
select 'B' as Name, count(*) as occurence from tableb where id = ?
union all
select 'C' as Name, count(*) as occurence from tablec where id = ?
union all
select 'D' as Name, count(*) as occurence from tabled where id = ?
```

Comment: you can quote the names if you want spaces: select count(*) as 'No of occurance'

Answer (score 0):

```
select id as Name,count(id) as occurence from tableA where id = 4 group by id
union all
select id as Name,count(id) as occurence from tableB where id = 4 group by id
union all
select id as Name,count(id) as occurence from tableC where id = 4 group by id
union all
select id as Name,count(id) as occurence from tableD where id = 4 group by id
```